# How to make a gouraud shading material

Tags: materials, node-editor, vertices, vertex-colors, shader-nodes

i would like to make a material that uses gouraud shading instead of phong :
[image: gouraud]

That means that the shader is per vertex and not per pixel, i thought i could use the parametric input but it didn't lead to anything

[image: parametric]

Also i just discovered pynodes but idk how to code so idk if it can be used here.
I know that i could bake the material to the vertex colors but i want it to be in real time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [N64 style vertex shading/lighting for low poly models?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208612/n64-style-vertex-shading-lighting-for-low-poly-models)

Comment: @Emir My answer there is _not_ Gouraud shaded.