# How to recreate PS1-style vertex lighting?

Tags: rendering, shaders, lighting

How would I recreate per-vertex lighting for a PS1-looking model? Vertex colours almost work, but they do not account for lighting. Is there a solution?

Example render:

[image: example]

Comment: Hello, could you add an example render ?

Comment: sure! the post has been updated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [N64 style vertex shading/lighting for low poly models?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208612/n64-style-vertex-shading-lighting-for-low-poly-models)

Comment: It's called the "Gouraud" shading, and AFAIK not supported by modern renderers. You can try to fake it aproximatively using the above link, but otherwise you would need a scanline renderer, like the one Blender used to have up until version 2.79 which you can download there: [Previous Versions — blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/)

Comment: I was hoping maybe someone did an OSL shader of it, but I haven't found any so far.